# How to communicate between NgModel component and pipe angular

Tags: angular

I created a component integrating an input field to perform a search but when I want to make it communicate with the pipe of searches the latter does not answer whereas when I integrate directly the field input in the body this last one communicates with the pipe.

**message-search component html**:

```
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchedTerm">
```

**message-search component ts**:

```
 import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'search-message',
    templateUrl: 'search-message.component.html'
  })
  export class SearchMessageComponent   {
  @Input() messageSearch: string;
 }
```

**app component html**:

```
   <search-message [messageSearch]="searchTerm"></search-message>
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of list | search: searchedTerm">
      <span [innerHTML]="item.name"></span>
    </div>
```

**app component ts**::

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
    searchTerm: string;
    list = [
     { 'id': 1, 'name': 'apple'},
     { 'id': 1, 'name': 'pineapple'},
     { 'id': 1, 'name': 'jackfruit'},
     { 'id': 1, 'name': 'somefruit'},
 ];
  }
```

**search filter pipe**:

```
     import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

     import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
     @Pipe({
       name: 'search'
     })
   export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

 constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 transform(list: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
   if (!list) { return []; }
   if (!searchText) { return list; }

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    let response = list.filter( item => {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
   });


     return response;
  }
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-searchpipe-gnqtgv

what would be the solution ?

Comment: You really do not need a pipe. This can be handled with array functions like filter. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-searchpipe-kmopd8

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky  I validate your solution that will avoid me to go through a pipe, thank you !

Comment: I’ll create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using a pipe to filter (and [probably should avoid it for performance reasons](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)) the array of data. Instead you can approach it in the following way. Create a new property on your component that represents the filtered list of data. Filtered results would be saved to this property to avoid mutating the original list:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  searchTerm: string;
  list = [
    { id: 1, name: "apple" },
    { id: 1, name: "pineapple" },
    { id: 1, name: "jackfruit" },
    { id: 1, name: "somefruit" }
  ];
  filteredList = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredList = this.list;
  }

  handleChange($event: string) {
    this.filteredList = this.list.filter(e => e.name.toLowerCase().includes($event));
  }
}

<search-message (searchChanged)="handleChange($event)"></search-message>
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of filteredList">
    <span [innerHTML]="item.name"></span>
</div>
```

In your search component, you can use [Output](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) (one approach) to emit the search string on change/input:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "search-message",
  templateUrl: "search-message.component.html"
})
export class SearchMessageComponent {
  searchedTerm: "";
  @Input() messageSearch: string;
  @Output() searchChanged = new EventEmitter<String>();

  handleChange() {
    this.searchChanged.emit(this.searchedTerm);
  }
}

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchedTerm" (input)="handleChange()">
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-searchpipe-kmopd8) in action.

I'd recommend reviewing the documentation/examples on [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) as it does a great job of showing different approaches to sharing data across components either through Input/Output or more preferably shared services.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could make it work like this

```
// search.component.html
 import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'search-message',
    templateUrl: 'search-message.component.html'
  })
  export class SearchMessageComponent   {
  @Input() messageSearch: string;
  searchedTerm: string; // <--- add this!
 }
```

```
// app.component.html
<search-message #search [messageSearch]="searchTerm"></search-message>
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of list | search: search.searchedTerm">
      <span [innerHTML]="item.name"></span>
    </div>
```

The real problem was the `searchedTerm` was not visible, in this way you could solve it.